# Roman numbers to decimal numbers, getting garbage value

Tags: c++, data-conversion, garbage, roman-numerals

I have to create a program for converting Roman numerals to decimal numbers for which I'm getting garbage value as an output. 
The fact is I have double checked my logic and it seems to be correct.

How can I correct it?

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class RomanType
{
  char str[10];
  int d;
public:
  void accept()
  {  
    cout<<"Enter Roman No. in capitals:"<<endl;
    cin>>str;
    convert(str);
  }

  void convert(char str1[10])
  {
    int j=0;

    for(j=0;j<strlen(str1);j++)
    {

    if( str1[j]=='I')
    {
        if(str1[j+1]=='V' || str1[j+1]=='X')
        {
            d=d-1;
            cout<<j<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            d=d+1;
            cout<<d<<endl;
        }
    }

    if ( str1[j]=='V')
        d=d+5;

    if(str1[j]=='X')
    {
        if(str1[j+1]=='L' || str1[j+1]=='C')
            d=d-10;
        else
            d=d+10;
    }

    if(str1[j]=='L')
        d=d+50;

    if( str1[j]=='C')
    {
        if(str1[j+1]=='D' || str1[j+1]=='M')
            d=d-100;
        else
            d=d+100;
    }

    if(str1[j]=='D')
        d=d+500;

    if(str1[j]=='M')
        d=d+1000;
    }
  }

  void display()
  {
    cout<<"It's decimal equivalent is="<<d<<endl;
  }
};

main()
{
  RomanType obj;
  obj.accept();
  obj.display();
}
```

Comment: you should use `std::string` instead of an array of `char`.

Comment: and tell us what input produce what garbage output

Comment: well i found that VI produces -1220155669, which for sure is wrong!

Comment: @Borgleader- Alright, but then how would I iterate through the string?

Comment: @pm100- Sadly for every input :(

Comment: [Just because I was interested](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/3amj28v9/) (it assumes a valid combination of numerals is supplied, there is no validation)

Comment: @MUSEFAN- Good alternative, but I wanted that to be in C++ and even better to find errors in my code! Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @sahildhawan: Yeah, it was just an example of working logic, just in case it was of any use ;)

Comment: @musefan- It did help, thanks. Now my code is working, you can see it. PS- I love 'time is running out', MuseFan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys thanks for the help. It's solved now. I had done a blunder and that was initialised d again in convert(), so that had made it as a local variable. See the comments:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class RomanType
{
char str[10];
int d;
public:
void accept()  // UNNECESSARILY NOT PASSING ANY STRING
{
    cout<<"Enter Roman No. in capitals:"<<endl;
    cin>>str;
    convert();
}

void convert()
{
     d=0;// PREVIOUSLY WRIITEN int d=0; so that was the mistake. Yay! it's solved :D


    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {

    if( str[j]=='I')
    {
        if(str[j+1]=='V' || str[j+1]=='X')
        {
            d=d-1;
           // cout<<d<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            d=d+1;
            //cout<<d<<endl;

        }

    }

    else if ( str[j]=='V')
        d=d+5;

    else if(str[j]=='X')
    {
        if(str[j+1]=='L' || str[j+1]=='C')
            d=d-10;
        else
            d=d+10;
    }

    else if(str[j]=='L')
        d=d+50;

    else if( str[j]=='C')
    {
        if(str[j+1]=='D' || str[j+1]=='M')
            d=d-100;
        else
            d=d+100;
    }

    else if(str[j]=='D')
        d=d+500;

    else if(str[j]=='M')
        d=d+1000;
    }


}

void display()
{
    cout<<"It's decimal equivalent is="<<d<<endl;
}
};

main()
{
RomanType obj;
obj.accept();
obj.display();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few points:

- Don't directly jump to parsing high value romans. Start with `I`, `V`, and `X` only (i.e. target 1 to 10 first, then 11 to 20, then 21 to 39, 40 to 99, 100 to 499 etc.)
- Don't assume that if `I` is given, it is given before or after `V` or `X`. It may be given for itself (eg. `II` - you else part assumes something).
- **Assign** value of `d` with **zero**
- Do step debugging, watch value of `d` and other variables. If debugger isn't good or available, do output the values on each step/iteration.
- [**Add**] You need not to pass `str` to function `convert`, since they belong to same class, and `convert` can/would read the same content.

Comment: Thanks Ajay for your last suggestion! I implemented it. Now my code is working perfectly since I had now wriiten d=0; Previously I had written int d=0; and so it was giving me garbage value.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize d to 0

in convert put d=0 at the start

Comment: What's the use of repeating my answer ?

Comment: we both typed it at the same time. Why did you repeat my answer :-)

Comment: Lol guys, calm down! Thanks for pointing out mistake, but I'm still getting garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `d` to 0. Please add this at the top of your `convert` function:

```
void convert(char str1[10])
{
    int j=0;
    d = 0;
    . . .
```

Comment: @fjardon- Thanks for the edit..But still I'm getting garbage value